# How do I use a custom cubic bezier for setView animations in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, easing

I'd like to use a custom cubic bezier when performing an animated `setView()` in Leaflet. I found out about `easeLinearity` in [Leaflet's pan options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#pan-options-easelinearity), but that only changes the third parameter of a cubic bezier curve:

> The curvature factor of panning animation easing (third parameter of the Cubic Bezier curve). 1.0 means linear animation, and the smaller this number, the more bowed the curve.

I tried using the `easeLinearity` option, but it just doesn't feel right.

What I'm looking for is a way to use an 'ease-in' or 'ease-in-out' type easing, or even a completely customized cubic bezier. Does anybody know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ease-out pan animation lives in [this very particular piece of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/2fa3117bc9b5ba433221df7d7b83034ba5ac9f20/src/dom/PosAnimation.js#L98):

```
_easeOut: function (t) {
    return 1 - Math.pow(1 - t, this._easeOutPower);
}
```

In order to switch to a custom easing function, you should:

- Subclass [`L.PosAnimation`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/dom/PosAnimation.js) and override either the `_step()` or the `_easeOut()` private methods.
- All instances of [`L.Map` spawn an instance of `L.PosAnimation`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/2fa3117bc9b5ba433221df7d7b83034ba5ac9f20/src/map/Map.js#L328). Override this by injecting an instance of your subclass into the (private) `_panAnim` property of your `L.Map` instance, preferably *before* any pan animation happens.

It's dirty, it's hackish, but it's possible.

Comment: Update: I ended up overriding the `flyTo()` method instead, because subclassing `L.PosAnimation` was only half the work. It turns out Leaflet only uses `L.PosAnimation` when doing a `panTo()`, which `setView()` uses when the zoom level stays the same.

By overriding `flyTo()`, I only had to monkeypatch one function that takes care of both pan and zoom at the same time. This gave me the power to use GSAP to make `flyTo()` feel really fancy! I only replaced ```function easeOut(t) { return 1 - Math.pow(1 - t, 1.5); }``` with ```function easeInOut(t) { return Power3.easeInOut.getRatio(t); }```